# create a map point for each member of an array js ArcGIS API

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I've created an array of volcanoes with latitudes and longitudes from a geoJSON file.
I would like to see if its possible to create a loop which iterates through the array to create points with the values.

Previously when I have attempted this I am presented with an empty map if it even loads.

My array is created such as

var div = document.getElementById('divholder');

```
  var divs = div.getElementsByClassName('volcdiv');
  var divArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
console.log(divs[i])
var volcanoname = divs[i].querySelector(".volcanoname").innerHTML
var volcanolat = divs[i].querySelector(".volcanolat").innerHTML
var volcanolon = divs[i].querySelector(".volcanolon").innerHTML
divArray.push({"volcanoname":volcanoname, "volcanolat": volcanolat, "volcanolon": volcanolon });
}
</script>
```

I'm looking to produce a variable like this

```
 var pointX = {
        type: "point",
        longitude: divArray[i].volcanolon,
        latitude: divArray[i].volcanolat,
    };
```

When attempting this without a for loop my plots do not point. Is there some issue with the values? or can they not be used with a map

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the result `divArray` value please, like `console.log(divArray)`.

Comment: @cabesuon Sure, log produces this for each volcano (this example is console.log(divArray[4]))                \n <p class="volcanoname" style="display: none;">Amukta</p>\n <p class="volcanolat" style="display: none;">52.50000</p>\n <p class="volcanolon" style="display: none;">-171.25200</p>\n

Comment: That looks more like `divs[4]`, I am guessing by looking at the code that `divArray[4]` should look like `{"volcanoname":x,"volcanolat": y,"volcanolon":z}`, can you confirm your output please

Comment: Sorry, I didnt realise I had some redundant code after. console.log(divarray[4]) produces:
`{volcanoname: 'Aniakchak', volcanolat: '56.88000', volcanolon: '-158.17000'}`

Comment: Mostly curious - but why not use the outofthebox GeoJSONLayer? 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GeoJSONLayer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a simple for loop which has now plotted all of the volcanoes. The map code looks like this.

```
require(["esri/Map", 
  "esri/views/MapView",
  "esri/Graphic",
  "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
  "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery"], 
  function(Map,
  MapView,
  Graphic,
    BasemapToggle,
    BasemapGallery
   )
   {
      var map3 = new Map({
        basemap: "topo"
      });
      var view3 = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv3", 
        map: map3, 
        zoom: 3, 
        center: [-130,15], 
      });
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
      const popupTemplate = {
          title: "{Name}",
          content: "{Description}"
      }
      const attributes = {
          Name: divArray[i].volcanoname,
          Description: "Longitude and Latitude: " + divArray[i].volcanolon + " " + divArray[i].volcanolat + " Elevation: " + divArray[i].volcanoelev + "M. Observation: " + divArray[i].volcanoobs + "."
      }
      
   var point3 = {
        type: "point",
        longitude: divArray[i].volcanolon,
        latitude: divArray[i].volcanolat,
    };

    var markerSymbol3 = {
        type: "simple-marker",
        color: [225, 0, 0],
  outline: {
      color: [0, 0, 0],
      width: 1.5
  }
    }

    var pointGraphic3 = new Graphic({
        geometry: point3,
        symbol: markerSymbol3,

        attributes: attributes,
        popupTemplate: popupTemplate
    })

    view3.graphics.add(pointGraphic3);
  }
    
    });
```